# How to change an html list element into the username of the currently logged in user by using Session?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is for a web app I'm working on, using JSP and Servlets. I've tried many suggestions from the internet, like a JS function that changes the text of the list element to the username, but it didn't work. It seems the problem is that the code inside my  tags does not recognize the username, although outside of the script tags it works well.

This is the last javascript function I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var username='<%= session.getAttribute("username") %>';
  document.getElementById("loginbutton").textContent=username;
</script>
```

This is the html for the list element:

```
<li id="loginbutton" class="loginbutton"><a href="login.jsp">Log in/Sign    up</a></li>`
```

As you can see from the code above, I created a variable that should hold the value of the username attribute from the session, and then by using textContent I tried to change the value of the loginbutton element to that of the username. The list element remains unchanged after I log in, so it is clear that the function does not get the username. Reminder that displaying the username outside of the JS code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do using the jsp.**

```
String user_label = session.getAttribute("username"); 
if(user_label == null){
    user_label = 'Log in/Sign    up';
}

<li id="loginbutton" class="loginbutton"><a href="login.jsp"><%=user_label%></a></li>`
```

**Using the javascript.**

get the session value outside the script.

```
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
```

when you get the username after successful login, use the name in java script to update the label

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var username = '<%=username %>';
 document.getElementById("loginbutton").text =username ;
</script>
```

Comment: Omg it worked! Finally! The javascript option didn't work for some reason, but the first one worked like a charm. Thank you!